# Error while extracting CSV from Excel file (Apache NiFi)

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache NiFi version **`1.16.3`** and trying to extract ***.csv*** from Excel file (***.xlsx***) with **ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor**. Size of the ***.xlsx*** is ***17 MB***, but I can't share it here.

I receive an error:
**org.apache.nifi.processors.poi.ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor.error**

*Tried to allocate an array of length **101,695,141**, but the maximum length for this record type is **100,000,000**. If the file is not corrupt or large, please open an issue on bugzilla to request increasing the maximum allowable size for this record type. As a temporary workaround, consider setting a higher override value with **IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride()***

What can I do with it? It says

> `consider setting a higher override value with IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride()`

as temprorary workaround, but where can I find this option? Seems like I should write custom processor with this option or what?

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace.

Comment: as a temporary solution, if you can, split the excel, pass them through the exceltocsv processors  and then merge their contents into one csv flow file by mergecontent processor